# What is the self._validate_dtype function for in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting my first contribution to an open source project on GitHub, but I am stuck at trying to figure out what a command is for/where it is defined.

```
def __init__(self, data=None, index=None, dtype=None, name=None,
             copy=False, fastpath=False):

    # we are called internally, so short-circuit
    if fastpath:

        # data is an ndarray, index is defined
        if not isinstance(data, SingleBlockManager):
            data = SingleBlockManager(data, index, fastpath=True)
        if copy:
            data = data.copy()
        if index is None:
            index = data.index

    else:

        if index is not None:
            index = _ensure_index(index)

        if data is None:
            data = {}
        if dtype is not None:
            dtype = self._validate_dtype(dtype)
```

The last line of this code snipped is what I'm referring to. I cannot find where _validate_dtype is defined. In that particular [file](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/series.py#L159), it appears only once, namely, in the code above. There is no import of it.

Comment: It is defined in [`../pandas/core/generic.py`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/generic.py#L164).

Comment: Awesome, thank you! How did you go about finding that out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github search is very handy for navigating repositories.

Try searching for _validate_dtype, like this:  https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=_validate_dtype

It's defined in [`pandas/core/generic.py`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/07ac39e9556538e02b3684bd7f4493c5301f409c/pandas/core/generic.py#L164)